# LOAD DATA INFILE error in php

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I want to import a csv file content into a database table, I'm using this code that it works **perfectly** when pasting it in phpmyadmin console:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testApp/trips.csv' INTO TABLE trips FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (type,startDate,endDate,steps,coordinates,distance)
```

However, when using it in a php file, I have an error:

```
<?php

$host       = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db         = "dbTest"; //Your database name
$user       = "root"; //Your database user
$pass       = "root"; //Your password
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database server connection failed.");
    die(mysqli_error($db));
} else {
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if (!$dbconnect) {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    } else {
        $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testApp/trips.csv' 
                INTO TABLE trips
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
               IGNORE 1 ROWS (type,startDate,endDate,steps,coordinates,distance)"
                ;

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
            $message = "The trip was successfully inserted!";
        } else {
            $message = "The trip insert failed";
            $message .= mysql_error();
        }

        echo $message;
    }
}
?>
```

=> `The trip insert failed`

I'm pretty sure that the problems come from a `\` or any other character that I can't target.
Thank you for helping .

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7638161/1745672

Comment: Are you sure you have \n as new line symbol? Try \r\n

Comment: Check it the query loads the file after you get this error.

Comment: You might have to escape the `\n` if you want to pass a backslash and an "n" instead of a newline.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `\\n` to mean a new line, but perhaps that it's not loading the file.

Comment: why you are mixing  mysql and mysqli functions??? check it carefully

Comment: Try die(dump($sql)); and check what is the $sql before $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

Comment: For tabular output, the “boxing” around columns enables one column value to be distinguished from another. For nontabular output (such as is produced in batch mode or when the --batch or --silent option is given), special characters are escaped in the output so they can be identified easily. Newline, tab, NUL, and backslash are written as `\n`, `\t`, \0, and \\. The --raw option disables this character escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**  You are mixing two plugins MYSQL and MYSQLi in same script, below i dumped remaining part of your code using mysqli plugin, because your upper part uses mysqli...

**N.B**:You can't do that. Pick just any single API.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) >= 1) {
        $message = "The trip was successfully inserted!";
    } else {
        $message = "The trip insert failed";
        $message .= mysqli_error($connection);
    }
```

Comment: A good answer explains what is wrong rather than just dumping replacement code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i have already commented that answer 45+ mins ago you can see it in comment section, thats why here i just dumped replacement  answer....ok never mind for your down vote...mam,best of luck

Comment: Comments are insufficient. Comments can be removed at any time. Comments supplement answers, not the other way around. The useful information from comments should be integrated into answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ok i'll try to follow it mam, thanks for advice/suggestion....

Comment: You solved my question dear Always Sunny, and you made my day more sunny! Your replacement code gains me more time, and unfortunately i'm not a php expert. Thank you .

Comment: Congratulations on stealing my answer (basically word for word!) and winning an accept with it. Good job.

Comment: words are insufficient. words can be removed/change at any time as you said to me previously to my comment @LightnessRacesinOrbit. thanks for down voting my answer. Be broad minded, you already 137k in your bag.....

Comment: Not the point. Plagiarism is _not_ cool, and swapping six of my words out for a lightly paraphrased version now that I've called you out on it is not fooling anybody. As for "words can be removed/change[d] at any time", no I didn't say that, I said _comments_ can be. Don't misrepresent me now!

Comment: i am just trying to mean that, you previously said,"Comments can be removed at any time", then words can also be changed/removed at any time. i am not misrepresenting you, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed up MySQL and MySQLi plugins — you're trying to connect with MySQLi then perform a query with MySQL. *You can't do that.* Pick *one* API and use it consistently.

So:

```
mysql_query($sql)     ---> $connection->query($sql)
mysql_affected_rows() ---> $result->affected_rows()
mysql_error()         ---> $connection->error
```

Ultimately, this has nothing to do with `LOAD DATA INFILE` and you should have tried it with a basic `SELECT`! And I recommend *reading the documentation* for the functions that you use.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm just struggling to get this work, the back office dev is in holidays. anyway ...

Answer (score -1):

Try to move you trip.csv file into `datadir` - You  can find it with this command : `SELECT @ @datadir`