# PHP : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got a problem when executing a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE via php.

`PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /blablabla`

Query is working with mysql directly, but it do no work with php.

I checked my local_infile from mysql, it is ok :

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+ 
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

There are some others questions about that but I can't modify source code (so PDO configuration in php code) :
[LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in... PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638090/load-data-local-infile-forbidden-in-php)

**EDIT :** I find how to configure pdo in my case, and I added PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true option in PDO.

I got an other error :

`[13:10:16] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version, query was: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/export_cat_28.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE tmp_pimgento_entities_category FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;`

Query still work with mysql directly.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: What path you use exactly ? (i suppose it's not blabla^^). Can you try with use `dirname(__FILE__).'/'.Your_Path` please ?

Comment: It is the path to my project. Here the full path :


```Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /home/soann-elosi/Documents/magento2project/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228```

Comment: FILE privilege is set for mysql user?

Comment: FILE privilege is set... :(

Comment: @SirBigoo have you solved this issue ?

Comment: @fxbois No I don't.
I reported an issue on the github's module which use that query. And the developper did not find out how to solve this, but it seems like a PHP bug.
He commited a fix to remove the LOCAL keyword.

I guess it's the only solution...

Comment: @SirBigoo I've solved this using `mysqli_init()`, `$link->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true)` and `$link->real_connect()` (instead of `new mysqli()`)

Answer (score 11):

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=ssldb',
    'username',
    'password',
    [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true]
);
```