# LOAD DATA INFILE from remote server getting error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, load-data-infile, loaddata

Trying to load `CSV` data to remote `MySQL Server` using following command in `MySQL Server 5.5`, and using `PHP-5.6` `PDO` connection.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE :file INTO TABLE test_csv COLUMNS 
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But i'm getting the following error:

> PHP Warning:  chown(): Unable to find uid for mysql in
>   /var/www/proj/csvtodb.php on line 22 2017-12-26 09:21:18,
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 13 Can't get stat of
>   '/tmp/csvfile-1.csv' (Errcode: 2)

Please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: Is the file located on the remote server or on the client server? If it's on the client server, you need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: The first warning has nothing to do with the MySQL query, it's from a call to `chown()` earlier in the script.

Comment: @barmar: csv file is in client server only

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV file is located on the PHP server running the script, not the remote MySQL server, you need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. `LOAD DATA INFILE` looks for the file on the MySQL server.

Comment: i changed as you said, still i'm getting following error                                                                
PHP Warning:  chown(): Unable to find uid for mysql in /var/www/proj/csvtodb.php on line 22
PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /var/www/proj/comm.php on line 445

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638090/load-data-local-infile-forbidden-in-php

Comment: The `chown()` error is because there's no username `mysql` in `/etc/passwd`, and you're trying to do something like `chown($filename, "mysql");`

Comment: i tried with this solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638090/load-data-local-infile-forbidden-in-php but still getting same error

Comment: Since it's a MySQL configuration problem of some kind, try asking in dba.stackexchange.com.